# Facebook Friends loop not working

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, codeigniter, loops

The following code gets the Facebook friends of the logged in user, and checks if any of his friends exist in a database table `gamers` using the `id` of the Facebook friends.

```
 $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

        foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {

            $friendid=$this->upload_model->get_user($value["id"]);

              if (($friendid)) {

                $my_friends=$this->upload_model->get_user($value["id"]);
                $data['top_friends']=$my_friends;



            }


        }
```

This code is in my controller of my codeigniter application, where `$this-upload_model->get_user()` is a function in my model that gets all the information on a `gamer`.

The model:

```
public function get_user($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $user=$this->db->get('gamers');
        $data = $user->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
```

In the view:

```
<?php foreach ($top_friends as $friend) : ?>

<p><?php echo $friend['name']; ?></p>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I want to achieve is to search if any of the Facebook friends of the logged in user are also registered and are stored in the database table `gamers`. All of the friends who exist in the database would have their info printed in the view.

Currently with this code, the view only prints one entry. The one entry printed is a Facebook friend, but it should list all, of which in this case there are 2 friends stored in the database. But this code only returns one.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you passing friends list in `top_friends`?

Comment: @kumar_v Please see the edit above. Sorry that was a typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass as array

```
$temp = array();
 foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {

            $friendid=$this->upload_model->get_user($value["id"]);

              if (($friendid)) {

                $my_friends=$this->upload_model->get_user($value["id"]);
                $temp[]=$my_friends[0];//as per your comment



            }
$data['top_friends'] = $temp;
```

Comment: Would anything have to change in the view? Tried this but I get errors, "Undefined index: name". 'name' is column in my `gamers` table. Please see the edit to question to view the model function

Comment: No change in view. I dont know how you are preparing data in $my_friends array / object. Just do print_r($temp); in controller. So you can see the structure of data.

Comment: It returns as `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fb_id] => 48301326 [username] => test [first_name] => gsv [last_name] => tsvt [email] => test@gmail.com [profile_pic] => [points] => 1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fb_id] => 505992134 [username] => fw [first_name] => bh [last_name] => bh [email] => ter@aol.com [profile_pic] => [points] => 2 ) ) )`

Comment: It prints out the data for the 2 friends data from the database.